# Signal handling in C

Tags: c, signals

I am figuring how signals work in C.
Here is one of the examples taken from old exams:

```
#include<signal.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<errno.h>

//#include <sys/types.h>

void handler1(int sig) {
 printf("Phantom");
 exit(0);
}
int main()
{
   pid_t pid1;
   signal(SIGUSR1, handler1); //installing signal handler
   if((pid1 = fork()) == 0) { //forking
       printf("Ghost");
       exit(0);
   }
   kill(pid1, SIGUSR1);
   printf("Ninja");
   return 0;
}
```

So far, GCC gives me two answers `Ghost Ninja` & `Ninja Phantom`. Could it produce `Ghost Phantom Ninja` or any other combination made of 3 names ?

One way I see it could possibly produce 3 names is: 
Fork, run in Child, print `Ghost`, exit(0) => in Parent, accept/process signal and from signal Handler print `Phantom`, kill child, print `Ninja`. But I am not sure if my "theory" holds the ground.

Also, would the `kill(pid1, SIGUSR1)` invoke `handler()` ?

Thanks !

Comment: Not an answer to the question as such, but you must **never** call printf() in a signal handler.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let's examine this line-by line. Set up a signal handler, then fork. The child prints "Ghost" and exits. The parent makes the child print "Phantom" and exit. Then the parent prints "Ninja".

So you've really got a race condition. If the parent fires its `SIGUSR1` before the child prints "Ghost", then you'll get `Phantom Ninja`, or perhaps `Ninja Phantom` (does kill block?)

But, if you can't get the signal off in time, then you'll get `Ghost Ninja` as the child finishes before the parent signals. I don't think the reverse is possible.

Now it is conceivable that the signal could be *exactly* on time to hit between the `printf` and the `exit`, in which case `Ghost` would finish, followed by `Phantom` then `Ninja` - or the reverse again, I think.

It's really finicky and sensitive to OS timing.

@Everyone - not tested! Feel free to contradict me, but I'll be as interested to know why as the OP.

Comment: "But, if you can't get the signal off in time, then you'll get Ghost Ninja as the child finishes before the parent signals. I don't think the reverse is possible."  If child exits, will parent proceed to kill or will it first accept the signal from handler ???

Answer (score 2):

Lets mark the lines with line numbers first as follows:

```
signal(SIGUSR1, handler1); //installing signal handler ---- 1
   if((pid1 = fork()) == 0) { //forking                ---- 2
       printf("Ghost");                                ---- 3
       exit(0);                                        ---- 4
 }
   kill(pid1, SIGUSR1);                                ---- 5
   printf("Ninja");                                    ---- 6
```

Now with the above code, if 
**Child executes first** and 
if 3 is executed first, then child is suspended and parent starts executing with 5. This will print *GhostPhantomNinja*

However, a definite order can not be determined.

Answer (score 0):

You have two non deterministic factors here, which are both depends on the OS: when will the context switching occur, and when will the signal arrive.

Since you can't control those, I'd answer that any order is possible. Try inserting wait() between command and see if you get the desired results.

Answer (score 0):

```
//#include <sys/types.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
void handler1(int sig) {
 printf("Phantom\n");
 waitpid(-1,NULL,0);
 //sexit(0);
}
int main()
{
   pid_t pid1;
   signal(SIGUSR1, handler1); //installing signal handler
        printf("my pid is %d ha ha parent..\n",getpid());
   //if((pid1 = fork()) == 0) { //forking
       pid1=fork();
       if(pid1==0)//in childe processs
       {
    printf("my pid is %d ha ha child..\n",getpid());
       printf("Ghost\n");
       sleep(6);
       exit(0);
   }
   else{
  //sleep(4); 
   kill(pid1, SIGUSR1);
   sleep(3);
   printf("Ninja\n");
   return 0;
}
}
```

Comment: try this out..use sleep as i have used then understand how the os works,i mean how the scheduler works..